# WordPress 3.2-: How to enable old (previous) fullscreen mode in TinyMCE editor, which has many buttons (style,font,...)

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Renewed fullscreen mode in WordPress has less buttons.
Is there a way to enable old (previous) fullscreen mode in TinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 0):

Add a "micro plugin" code described in [Ticket #20237](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20237).

```
    add_filter('mce_buttons', 'oldfullscreen_mce_buttons');
    function oldfullscreen_mce_buttons($buttons) {
        $buttons[] = 'fullscreen';
        return $buttons;
    }
```

Reference:

WordPress › Support » Full screen editing with formatting buttons
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/full-screen-editing-with-formatting-buttons

WordPress › Support » [Plugin: TinyMCE Advanced] Appear in full screen mode?
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-tinymce-advanced-appear-in-full-screen-mode?replies=2